# How do Apple do this? (iPhone 4 commercial)

Tags: stabilisation, iphone, apple

Take a look at this short iPhone 4 advert...

How do they keep the phone so stable throughout the video? If you have ever tried to hold something completely still in close up, it’s extremely difficult.

If you look very closely, the left hand appears to shift very slightly in relation to the phone. This would imply the phone is fixed onto a mount, but the initial section amd the move at 25s show that it’s not.

I have tried using software stabalisation in post, but this does not look convincing.

Is the screen of the iPhone superimposed in post, over a still hand and device? This seems unlikely I think.

Any thoughts on this would be very welcome.

Answer (score 2):

It's a still. For commercial beauty shots like those, you hire a hand model and freeze frame the video once the phone is held. The screen is obviously just a Greenscreen or simply black so it can be replaced afterwards. Then, the finger swipes etc are recorded seperately (probably in front of a Greenscreen) and then composited onto the screen to fit the animation.

Answer (score 0):

The hand with phone is freezed. Than they overlay the hand motions (Probablly shot with green screen) and animate the phone screen.